# Why should we always use our real names while generating GPG key?

Tags: git, gnupg

I'm using GPG to sign my `git` commits as the project I'm working for wants.

But I use a pseudonym and I don't want to be identified like by my GPG signature.

Over [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GnuPrivacyGuardHowto#Using_GnuPG_to_generate_a_key):  it asks us to use only our real names (as in our passport or government issued ID).

What is the necessity? How can I maintain my anonymity with GPG?

Comment: Support project which encourages anonymous contributions.

Comment: Weird tagging!!! Question is not related to git or GNUPG at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, this advice is linked to **[CLA (Contribution License Agreement)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contributor_License_Agreement)**, which defines the terms under which intellectual property has been contributed to a company/project, typically software under an open source license.

The [Canonical contributor licence agreement](http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/contributors) for Ubuntu [mentions in its FAQ](http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/contributors/licence-agreement-faq) that it uses now a copyright licence agreement (where the contributor grants permission for Canonical to distribute the contribution).

The [Canonical Individual Contributor License Agreement](http://assets.ubuntu.com/sites/ubuntu/latest/u/files/section/legal/Canonical-HA-CLA-ANY-I_v1.2.pdf) is a deal between "You" and Canonical, so if you are using your GPG key, attaching it to a contribution to Canonical, its metadata should reflect "You" (actual name or address), in order for the [IP (Intellectual Property)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellectual_property) to be respected.

There are projects like [CLAHub (Contributor License Agreements on GitHub)](https://www.clahub.com/) to make the process easier, but if you are using a GPG key for contributing to an open source project in the context of a CLA, then the information should be accurate.

If you are using the GPG key in any other context, you can associate any metadata (name/email, ...) that you want.

Answer (score 2):

It's **not necessary**. You referenced

- recommendation|agreement
- For Ubuntu-world only

But (is [Wiki-reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy#Web_of_trust) OK for you?):

> when verifying signatures, it is critical that the public key used to
>   send messages to someone or some entity actually does 'belong' to the
>   intended recipient. Simply downloading a public key from somewhere is
>   not an overwhelming assurance of that association; deliberate (or
>   accidental) impersonation is possible

because I can see (and get) a lot of different "learner"'s signatures, I want (under some conditions) be sure, **who** is each "learner" and know - is it the same person or I have any type of impersonation

**PS:** <sub>[Security](http://security.stackexchange.com) site of SE-family may be better and more relevant location for such type of questions</sub>